# USB devices not mounted

Tags: usb, mount, virtualbox

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on VirtualBox. I've installed Guest Additions on Ubuntu but my USB devices still don't get mounted. I tried using the USB filters on VirtualBox, but even after that the devices is not mounted. When I click on the devices it shows this:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/aditya/9E02-9AB8: Command-line `mount -t "vfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/aditya/9E02-9AB8"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so
```

Please help me to mount the devices on the ubuntu.

Comment: This is the output of sudo blkid /dev/sdb1   /dev/sdb1: UUID="9E02-9AB8" TYPE="vfat"

Comment: Thanks. So we have that covered. Could you please perform a file system check on it, e. g. with GParted or `sudo fsck -n /dev/sdb1`?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Here is the output of this command                                       fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
fsck.fat 3.0.26 (2014-03-07)
/dev/sdb1: 0 files, 1/965789 clusters

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Host system must make those devices available. It is not just about configuring the guest OS.  You did not say what your host OS is, that may be the problem.

In the Oracle VM box, choose the VM you are interested in (don't start it), then click the settings icon. USB configuration is toward the bottom.  Mine says "Enable USB" and "USB 2.0".

Then you can start the VM and find out if it sees the media.

You may experience a conflict between the host and the guest over control of USB. There is a long thread about it here:

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=45349

May be as easy as "eject" the USB when the host OS grabs it, allowing guest to have a try at it.

That pre-supposes you know how, in Ubuntu, to mount a USB stick.

If you don't see USB as an option in VBox settings, it means you did not yet install the Extensions package for Virtual Box (different from guest addon thing). https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

I expect these things will help you fix it. If this fails, the last idea is to change your Oracle packages.  If you are using VB packages from the Ubuntu, maybe you should stop. The Ubuntu package of Virtual Box is different than the packages direct from Oracle.  The Debian/Ubuntu folks break up the different pieces in a way that makes setting this up more difficult for me. I did not try since 2015. Since then I always use the Oracle packages.  If you keep hitting trouble, best to configure the Oracle repo. You know the drill, /etc/apt/sources.list.d, put this in a file "oracle.list" for example:

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian yakkety contrib
```

You'll need to get a security key for that ( https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads).